# how to have notebook output be in cell format consistently for easy excel pasting?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How do I get the output of a jupyter notebook to be in cell format for easy copy into excel? Like

[image]
instead of

[image]

I had thought it was with the display module but looks like that's not the reason.

Sorry for the large imagine, not sure why it's blown up like this..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)? If that's so, you can export your data to an excel file directly or render your table as html and then copy and paste the data you need.

Comment: Actually solved my issue, turns out display only works with panda's dataframe, not it's series format so I just needed to convert my vector series into a dataframe. But thanks!